# Get WPF window by hWnd

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi

I am looking to get a WPF window and traverse it's controls. I'm able to get the hWnd and i've found other posts on traversing the controls using a DependencyObject. How do I get a DependencyObject from a hWnd? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you doing this from within the same process, or from a separate process? You can typically only access WPF objects within the same AppDomain (which in turn restricts you to within your same process). Could you give more background on why you want to traverse the controls - perhaps automation/testing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Window window = (Window)HwndSource.FromHwnd(hWnd).RootVisual
```

Comment: this is what i'm trying but RootVisual is always null.

Comment: Maybe your hWnd targeting Window that doesn't belong to WPF? How you obtain hWnd?

Comment: obtained hwnd using FindWindowEx and I also got the same value using EnvDTE.Window.HWnd property. Spy++ shows a different hwnd than what i get.

Comment: Can you tell us why do you need to find this Window? Perhaps there will be another solution instead of using native handles ;)

Comment: Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. Making a collapse all function. It doesn't have one built in and EnvDTE doesn't have one either it only has ExpandView() which of course opens everything.

Comment: Solution Explorer is still native

Comment: @Marat so what do you think? How can I get the context of the tree so I can work with it?

Comment: @DustinDavis I have the same problem, how did you solve it without hwnd?

Comment: @Sven Since I was building a Visual Studio extension, I ended up finding a different way to accomplish what I needed, so hwnd wasn't even needed. Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: @DustinDavis that's what I took from EnvDTE ;) I'm in the same boat, so my question still stands: how did you do it?

Comment: @Sven I don't recall, but here is the project I was building at the time which has the feature I was trying to accomplish in my question https://dfactor.codeplex.com/ it will have the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know WPF completely replaces WinApi model with all that HWNDs. Main window has HWND of course, because it servers as container between WinApi and WPF. You can access HWND using [WindowInteropHelper Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx), like [this](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-get-hwnd-and-hook-into-wndproc.html). But you will not be able to traverse controls the same way you would do it with native or WinForms app. Check [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) for traversing control trees in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the window itself (as Marat points out how to do that) you need to search the visual tree. Here are two helper functions

find all children of a type

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(this DependencyObject source) where T : DependencyObject
    {
      if (source != null)
      {
        var childs = GetChildObjects(source);
        foreach (DependencyObject child in childs)
        {
          //analyze if children match the requested type
          if (child != null && child is T)
          {
            yield return (T)child;
          }

          //recurse tree
          foreach (T descendant in FindChildren<T>(child))
          {
            yield return descendant;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

https://sites.google.com/site/bobstechwiki/home/wpf-ji-shu-1/find-element-by-visual-tree

to find a child by name:

```
 public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
       where T : DependencyObject
    {    
      // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
      if (parent == null) return null;

      T foundChild = null;

      int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
      for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
      {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
          // recursively drill down the tree
          foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

          // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
          if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
          var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
          // If the child's name is set for search
          if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
          {
            // if the child's name is of the request name
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          // child element found.
          foundChild = (T)child;
          break;
        }
      }

      return foundChild;
    }
```

[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)

Comment: I already have this as stated in my question. I'm trying to get the window from a hWnd so I can get to this point.

Comment: Indeed, Marat's answer should do that. Just added this for completeness in case someone stumbles upon this and needed to know the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a special case not documented here yet. It could be that the toplevel control is not a standard WPF `Window`. This is the case (for instance) in Visual Studio 2010. I discovered this when writing a visual studio Add-in: I wanted to inject some WPF controls in the visual tree, but you need the start of the WPF tree.

Fortunately, there is a solution:

```
  var hwnd = _dte.MainWindow.HWnd;
  var window = HwndSource.FromHwnd((IntPtr)hwnd);
  dynamic customWindow = window.RootVisual;
  UIElement content = customWindow.Content;
```

The trick is that by declaring the `customWindow` as `dynamic` you don't need to know or specify its type. In good WPF fashion it has a `Content` property that contains all the window's content and everything is normal from there.