# Change win app labels and text

Tags: c#, winforms

I remember in `VB6` i was able to get the handle of a form of a software that's currently running, and change it from outside with some API functions.
Is it possible to do with c#? how? The problem is that this software is in a different language. I want to change some of it to English.

Comment: have you searched stackoverflow? simple search yielded lots of similar questions : for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822026/get-wpf-window-by-hwnd

Comment: That's for WPF though, which doesn't appear very similar to the answers given here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `FindWindow` and `SetWindowText` from Win32 API:

***`FindWindow`*** c# signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

***`SetWindowText`*** c# signature:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, String lpString);
```

and a sample cod:

```
SetWindowText(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, "Hello W");
```

Answer (score 1):

1) In WinForms there is an "Handle" property in Control class (all controls and Form class derive from it ([MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx))

2) In WPF there is no HWND handle exposed, but you can get it by using [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) class.
 you can get it like this:

```
        WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(YourWindow);
        IntPtr hwndHandle = wih.Handle;
```